# How to concatenate values of repeating column value using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I read a csv file:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path, sep='\t', 
    names=["id", "beer", "soda", "water", "name"])
```

The file looks as follows:

```
01  0   1   0   John
04  1   1   0   John
51  0   1   1   John
52  0   1   0   John
87  0   0   0   Adam
141 0   1   0   Lisa
176 1   1   0   Lisa
177 0   1   0   Lisa
263 1   0   0   Jack
269 0   1   1   Jack
275 0   0   0   Jack
281 0   1   0   Jack
305 0   1   0   Thomas
325 0   1   1   Jacob
331 1   0   0   Jacob
355 0   0   0   Jacob
```

I need to combine or concatenate the values by name, so they would look like this and write the result to the new file:

```
01  1   1   0   John
87  0   0   0   Adam
141 1   1   0   Lisa
269 1   1   1   Jack
305 0   1   0   Thomas
305 1   1   1   Jacob
```

The id column is not important it can be whatever. I know how to write to the file, however, I can't find a way on how to concatenate values.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
out = df.groupby('name',as_index=False).max()
```

Comment: It worked as aspected. Thank you very much :)